# add space to /dev/sda1 kali linux

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, kali-linux, disk-space, disk-cleanup

i have never done such operations on my kali linux. I want to add more disk space and I have done the following.

1. In Virtual Box settings I have added more space.
2. Done

This has added more space on the udev filesystem , around 12 gb.
I want to merge this space to my working disk /dev/sda1 which is full
If I am doing something wrong correct me, I want just to add some more space.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            12600904       0  12600904   0% /dev
tmpfs            2524464     936   2523528   1% /run
/dev/sda1        7205476 6714324    105412  99% /
tmpfs           12622300  224440  12397860   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            2524460      68   2524392   1% /run/user/1001
```

why udev has got this amout of space?

Comment: Did you _actually_ add disk space, and not RAM space?

Comment: RAM != hard disk?

Comment: yes, this was ram lol, my bad